# AWS Cognito server to server auth on behalf of the user

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito with the web application. It works well, users can sign in and AWS API Gateway Authorizer is added to check the auth on backend.

But now I want to create a separate API which would be server-to-server REST API, and it should auth some user not using a password.

So I created two client apps in Cognito one for the web and another for public API. But how I can log a user with no password via the public API app? I want to show some form in the web app which would allow users to use public API.

Comment: Are you looking for the Oauth 2.0 "on-behalf-of" flow? The only docs I could find for this are for Microsoft's Identity Server.